# Group by multiple fields and filter by common value of a field

Tags: java, java-stream

```
@Data
public class Employee{

    private int empid;
    private  String empPFcode;
    private String collegeName;
}

Employee emp1=new Employee (1334090,"220","AB");
Employee emp2=new Employee (1334091,"220","AB");
Employee emp3=new Employee (1334092,"220","AC");
Employee emp4=new Employee (1434091,"221","DP");
Employee emp5=new Employee (1434091,"221","DP");
Employee emp6=new Employee (1434092,"221","DP");
```

I want to filter this `Employee` object based on the `EmpPFcode` . If `collegeName` has common value for 3 `EmpPFcode`, we will collect otherwise we will skip that records.

So my result would be like below.

```
Employee emp4=new Employee (1434091,"221","DP");
Employee emp5=new Employee (1434091,"221","DP");
Employee emp6=new Employee (1434092,"221","DP");
```

Below one will skip because `collageName` is different.

I try to do some logic below but it doesn't not filter properly.

```
List<CombinedDTO> distinctElements = list.stream().filter(distinctByKeys(Employee ::empPFcode,Employee ::collegeName))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());


public static <T> Predicate <T> distinctByKeys(Function<? super T, Object>... keyExtractors) {
     Map<Object, Boolean> uniqueMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

     return t ->
     {
         final List<?> keys = Arrays.stream(keyExtractors)
                 .map(ke -> ke.apply(t))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());

         return uniqueMap.putIfAbsent(keys, Boolean.TRUE) == null;
     };
}
```

Comment: So once you filter for `empPFcode == "221"`, shouldn't the empid 1434091 be excluded?

Comment: It can't be excluded.

Comment: Result can be like 
Employee emp4=new Employee (1434091,"221","DP");
Employee emp5=new Employee (1434092,"221","DP");
Employee emp6=new Employee (1434093,"221","DP");

Comment: If collegeName is unique for all same empPFcode  . then it will select otherwise it can be skip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I. Solution:***

A more cleaner and readable solution would be to have a set of `empPFcode` values (`[221]`), then filter the employee list only by this set.

First you can use `Collectors.groupingBy()` to group by `empPFcode`, then you can use `Collectors.mapping(Employee::getCollegeName, Collectors.toSet())` to get a set of `collegeName` values.

```
Map<String, Set<String>> pairMap = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getEmpPFcode,
        Collectors.mapping(Employee::getCollegeName, Collectors.toSet())));
```

will result in: `{220=[AB, AC], 221=[DP]}`

Then you can remove the entries which includes more than one `collegeName`:

```
pairMap.values().removeIf(v -> v.size() > 1);
```

will result in: `{221=[DP]}`

The last step is filtering the employee list by the key set. You can use `java.util.Set.contains()` method inside the filter:

```
List<Employee> distinctElements = list.stream().filter(emp -> pairMap.keySet().contains(emp.getEmpPFcode()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

***II. Solution:***

If you use `Collectors.groupingBy()` nested you'll get a `Map<String,Map<String,List<Employee>>>`:

```
{
   220 = {AB=[...], AC=[...]}, 
   221 = {DP=[...]}
}
```

Then you can filter by the map size (`Map<String,List<Employee>>`) to eliminate the entries which has more than one map in their values (`AB=[...], AC=[...]`).

You still have a `Map<String,Map<String,List<Employee>>>` and you only need `List<Employee>`. To extract the employee list from the nested map, you can use `flatMap()`.

Try this:

```
List<Employee> distinctElements = list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getEmpPFcode, Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getCollegeName)))
                .entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue().size() == 1).flatMap(m -> m.getValue().values().stream())
                .flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it.  I added some extra values to the list of Employee's.

```
List<Employee> list =
        List.of(new Employee(1334090, "220", "AB"),
                new Employee(1334091, "220", "AB"),
                new Employee(1334092, "220", "AC"),
                new Employee(1434091, "221", "DP"),
                new Employee(1434091, "221", "DP"),
                new Employee(1434092, "221", "DP"),
                new Employee(1434091, "222", "AB"),
                new Employee(1434091, "222", "AB"));
```

- create a map of maps based first on `empPFcode` as the key
- then as `collegeName` as the key.
- if the inner map size is greater than 1 for the college key, then exclude it since it has extra collegeNames for the empPFcode.
- then simply flatten the inner map to its `entrySet` and pull off the value which will be the Employee object.

```
List<Employee> results = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getEmpPFcode,
                Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Employee::getCollegeName)))
        .values().stream().filter(map -> map.size() == 1)
        .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
        .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

 results.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
[1434091,  221,  DP]
[1434091,  221,  DP]
[1434092,  221,  DP]
[1434091,  222,  AB]
[1434091,  222,  AB]
```

Here is the modified class

```
class Employee {
    
    private int empid;
    private String empPFcode;
    private String collegeName;
    
    public Employee(int empid, String empPFcode,
            String collegeName) {
        this.empid = empid;
        this.empPFcode = empPFcode;
        this.collegeName = collegeName;
    }
    
    public int getEmpid() {
        return empid;
    }
    
    public String getEmpPFcode() {
        return empPFcode;
    }
    

    public String getCollegeName() {
        return collegeName;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("[%s,  %s,  %s]", empid, empPFcode,
                collegeName);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thx, Can we also distinct value of above result

Comment: Yes.  For example you could have a  `Map<Integer,List<Employee>>`.  The key would be the employee ID.  But if each Employee for a given ID is the same equivalent object, it may make more sense to have `Map<Integer, Employee>` and then just have one Employee Object instead of a List of all of them.  It all depends on your requirements.